# Subscribe to .ics with outlook 2013

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

My web-app generates an ical-feed for users to subscribe to. Works fine in Google Calender, and in Office 365/ Outlook.com using ’My Calendars’ > Open Calendar > Internet calendar.

When trying to add the calender from Outlook 2013 using My Calendars > Add Calendar > From Internet and paste the url, nothing happens. Nothing as in: also no errors. The feed is using https, think Microsoft prefers webcal.

When the feeds is added from web, it does show up and works correctly in Outlook.

It's pretty confusing for my users especially as there are no errors given; nothing happens at all.

What do I have to change to my feed to make it work from Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

The current forum is for developers. That's why I'd suggest asking such questions on the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Outlook IT Pro Discussions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=outlook) forums.